# Spring 3 oracle schema wrapped by quotes

Tags: java, spring, oracle, criteria

I have a problem after update project to Spring 3.
There is schema wrapped by quotes:

```
    StandardTableGroup (f1 : path.entity.scheduler.FffMessagesEntity(523113009709800)) {
      primaryTableReference : "dfc$scm".fff_messagesas f1_0
```

And result ORA-00942

```
[http-nio-9098-exec-1] DEBUG Request: - JDBC exception executing SQL [select * from "dfc$scm".fff_messages f1_0 where f1_0.fum_status in(?,?)] [n/a]
```

Entity class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "fff_messages", schema = "Sdfc$scm")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_fff_messages", sequenceName="SEQ_fff_messages", schema  = "dfc$scm", allocationSize = 1)
public class FffMessagesEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_fff_messages")
@Column(name = "FUM_ID", nullable = false, length = 10)
private BigInteger fumId;

other fields
```

CriteriaBuilder:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public List<Dto> getName() {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Dto> cq = cb.createQuery(Dto.class);
    Root<FffMessagesEntity> root = cq.from(FffMessagesEntity.class);

    cq.multiselect(root.get(FffMessagesEntity_.fumId),
            root.get(FffMessagesEntity_.fumMessageName),
            root.get(FffMessagesEntity_.fumMessageBody),
            root.get(FffMessagesEntity_.uniqGuid));

    cq.where(root.get(FctUnprocessedMessageEntity_.status).in(1, 2));

    try {
        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried use spring-boot-starter-parent another version (3.2.2), but there is same exception. So, on spring 2.7.1 no problem. I understand query is forming not by spring, but version of dependencies are difrent.

Comment: `oracle db` works with schema name enclosed in double quotes. enclosing the schema name in double quotes is considered an instruction for Oracle DB to make the schema name case insensitive. That might not be your issue. are you using the same user in Spring Boot `v2` vs `v3` to connect to db? if yes, it could be an entitlements issue. did you try running the same query (with schema name in double quotes) directly on db?